# Get SecKeyRef from modulus/exponent

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, rsa

I have a RSA key (pair) represented as big integeger modulus and exponent and need to encrypt/decrypt with those.

I figured out how to handle keys as needed in iOS using swift.

To my question: Is there any way to convert the modulus/exponent representation to a standard SecKeyRef?

Both is formatted as big int (coming from android), 
a modulus for example looks like this:

> 23986589886077318012326064844037831693417390067186403792990846282531380456965701688980194375481519508455379138899060072530724598302129656976140458275478340281694599774176865257462922861492999970413042311221914141827738166785420817621605554859384423695247859963064446809695729281306530681131568503935369097838468173777374667631401317163094053418212485192857751897040859007584244053136110895205839896478287122804119514727484734998762296502939823974188856604771622873660784676915716476754048257418841069214486772931445697194023455179601077893872576165858771367831752886749210944303260745331014786145738511592470796648651

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same task - given a modulus and an exponent I had to create a public key and encrypt a message using that key. After a long time spent in reading and trying various libraries, I was able to accomplish this with OpenSSL. I'm posting my way of doing it below. Although it's written in Objective-C, it might be helpful.

```
NSData* message, modulus, exponent;
BIGNUM* mod = BN_bin2bn((unsigned char *)[modulus bytes], (int)modulus.length, NULL);
if (mod == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating modulus BIGNUM");
}

BIGNUM* exp = BN_bin2bn((unsigned char *)[exponent bytes], (int)exponent.length, NULL);
if (exp == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating exponent BIGNUM");
}

RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
rsa->pad = 0;
rsa->e = exp;
rsa->n = mod;

int keylen = RSA_size(rsa);
unsigned char* enc = malloc(keylen);
char* err = malloc(130);
int status = RSA_public_encrypt((int)message.length, (const unsigned char*)[message bytes], enc, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);

if (status != -1) {
    NSData* encryptedMessage = [NSData dataWithBytes:enc length:keylen];
    NSLog(@"Encryption SUCCESSFUL: %@", encryptedMessage);
}
else {
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
    NSLog(@"Encryption failed with error: %s", err);
}

free(enc);
free(err);
```

So first I'm creating big integers out of my `NSData` modulus and exponent. You already have them as big integers, but if they're not represented as OpenSSL's `BIGNUM` type, you'll have to convert them. `BIGNUM` has other useful functions for creating big integers like `BN_hex2bn` and `BN_dec2bn` - these create big integers out of C strings containing hexadecimal or decimal numbers. In my case the modulus and exponent are stored as a byte array in an `NSData` and `BN_bin2bn` creates a `BIGNUM` directly from that.

Moving on, I create an `RSA` structure which represents a key and holds the modulus and exponent, and the `enc` buffer, which will hold the raw encrypted bytes. The length of `enc` is the same as the size of the key, because RSA can not encrypt messages longer that the key.

The main work is done by the `RSA_public_encrypt()` function. It takes five arguments - the size of the message that you're going to encrypt, the actual message bytes, an output buffer to store the encrypted message in, the RSA key and a padding scheme. I'm using no padding here, because my message is exactly the same size as the key, but in the `rsa.h` there are macros that represent the most common padding schemes.

Lastly I check the `status` which holds the number of encrypted bytes and print an error message if something went wrong.

I hope this will help you and somebody else. Tell me if you managed to do it in Swift. Cheers ;-)

P.S. Adding OpenSSL to your iOS project is easy using CocoaPods. Just add

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '1.0.1.k'
```

to your podfile.